# How can I get a string from the user in java?

Tags: java, io

I am using the code below to get a string in Java to use it as a file path, but it has an error.  I checked tat the address is correct but I don't know what the exact problem is?

```
String filename;
System.out.print("please write down the address of your specefic file:(please insert double '\\'instead of one '\')");
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
filename=input.nextLine();
File n=new File(filename);
System.out.print(n.getPath());
compress(n);
```

Comment: For better help sooner, try posting an SSCCE  http://pscode.org/sscce.html

Comment: You need to be more specific than "it has an error."  Tell us exactly what is happening and when vs what you expect to happen and why.

Comment: Which error and please add an example?

Comment: `address of your specefic file:(please insert double '\\'instead of one '\'` That won't work very well on OS X or *nix. ;)  (And it is spelled 'specific' 2 'i's, 1 'e'.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enter you input normally, not with double `\\`. The java code you are invoking to create the file will take care of correctly escaping the `\` characters.

Comment: Or rather, they don't *need* to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exact error I would think you're probably entering strings like

```
C:\\test.txt
```

so java escapes the input and tries to open

```
File n = new File("C:\\\\test.txt");
```

which *may* throw an error.

Comment: thanks the main problem was this.i write down the address without the format of it

Answer (score 0):

This code works just fine:

```
String filename;
System.out.print("please write down the address of your specefic file:(please insert double '\\'instead of one '\')");
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
filename=input.nextLine();
File n=new File(filename);
System.out.print(n.getPath());
```

> please write down the address of your specefic file:(please insert
>   double '\'instead of one '')
>   /Users/acuga/Downloads/sitemap.xml
>
> /Users/acuga/Downloads/sitemap.xml

Either it's something wrong with the `compress()` method, or the path is being entered incorrectly.

Please show the error you are getting.